# Get textbox content when it's edited

Tags: c#, wpf

I wnat to make a kind of search textbox when the user would input some text to the texbox it will search for him, therefore I want to know what the textbox content, for now I have:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
...

<TextBox Text="{Binding Search}" >
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
              <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>
           </i:EventTrigger>
       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </TextBox>
```

At the viewModel:

```
public ICommand SearchCommand { get; private set; }
public MyViewModel()
{
  SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(SearchMethod);
}

void SearchMethod()
 {
   if(Search==null)
     MessageBox.Show("Search text is null");
 }
string search;
public string Search
{
        get { return search; }
        set
        {
            Set(() => Search, ref search, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("Search");
        }
 }
```

But every time that I input some text to the textbox it shows the message: `Search text is null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the binding is evaluated when the **TextBox loses focus**. Your event is fired anytime a key is pressed.

To change this behavior, you can set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` in the Binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Search, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: It works now, but the content it is always one step back, i.e if I enter `abc` so in ViewModel I have `ab`

Comment: Maybe you should use `KeyUp` insted of `KeyDown` event. This should get fired later

Comment: ...or you completely remove the event and call the filtering method at the end of the setter of `Search` property

Comment: It calls the event at each key press, the problem is is that the "Search" content is alwawys one letter missing (the last one)

Comment: Then use `TextChanged` event, this is working for me